twisted reactor not launching tasks on raspberry pi
I don't know why this code works on my windows computer, but just blocks on my raspberry pi.
from twisted.internet import reactor, ssl, threads
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientFactory, WebSocketClientProtocol
import queue
from queue import Empty
import threading
import time

connection_signal = threading.Event()


class MyWebSocketClientProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):
    def onOpen(self):
        print("WebSocket connection opened.")
        self.factory.client_protocol = self

    def onConnect(self, response):
        print(f"Server connected: {response.peer}")
        connection_signal.set()

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print(f"WebSocket connection closed: {reason}")

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        print(f"Message received: {payload}")


class WebSocketManager:
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue
        self.client_protocol = None

    def connect(self, host, port):
        self.factory = WebSocketClientFactory(f"wss://{host}:{port}")
        self.factory.protocol = MyWebSocketClientProtocol
        context_factory = ssl.ClientContextFactory()
        reactor.connectSSL(host, port, self.factory, context_factory)
        connection_signal.wait()

    def disconnect(self):
        self.factory.client_protocol.sendCloseFrame()

    def send_message(self, message):
        self.factory.client_protocol.sendMessage(message.encode("utf-8"))


def reactor_thread(queue):
    manager = WebSocketManager(queue)

    def process_queue():
        while True:
            try:
                msg = queue.get(timeout=0.1)
                if msg:
                    if msg == "connect":
                        manager.connect("192.168.2.98", 8000)
                        time.sleep(0.1)  # allow the connection to be established
                    elif msg == "disconnect":
                        manager.disconnect()
                    else:
                        manager.send_message(msg)
            except Empty:
                pass

    reactor.callInThread(process_queue)
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)


def main():
    message_queue = queue.Queue()
    reactor_thread_instance = threading.Thread(
        target=reactor_thread, args=(message_queue,)
    )
    reactor_thread_instance.start()

    message_queue.put("connect")
    message_queue.put("Hello WebSocket!")
    message_queue.put("disconnect")
    time.sleep(5)
    # reactor.stop()
    # reactor_thread_instance.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I've seen my computer runs select reactor, while the raspberry runs epoll reactor, but I tried forcing select on raspberry and epoll on computer and nothing changes.
I've detected that the raspberry pi never call the __init__ of the class MyWebSocketClientProtocol, while the computer does.
In both venv, the library and pythons are same versions (autobahn == 23.6.2, twisted == 23.10.0, pyopenssl == 24.2.1, python3.12)

This isn't the correct way to use Twisted.  The multiple threads in the code in your question might sometimes work by accident but as you've discovered it is not reliable.  Twisted is a cooperative multitasking system that runs (almost) exclusively in a single thread.  The APIs are largely not thread-safe.  Twisted provides its own abstractions for event notification (Deferred) and time-based scheduling (IReactorTime) that, as a first approximation, you need to use instead of threading.Event and time.sleep.
The code in your question sometimes hangs because Twisted's APIs aren't meant to be called from multiple threads as you're doing.  The program may sometimes produce results something like what you expect because of accidents of timing but a program structured like this will never work reliably.
